# MySQL double left join doubles result which changes column sum result

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I would like to left join three tables in one result and when I'm doing it like that: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/546c24/2 my result is wrong as you see.

I want `COUNT(Test2.id)` to be `2` and `SUM(Test3.positive)` to be `3` and not both 6.

That's my problem. I hope it's understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a Cartesian product for each `test1.id`.  You need to aggregate *before* the `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT t1.id,Test1.name, t2.cnt_2,
       t3.sum_pos, t3.sum_neg
FROM Test1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ID_Test1, COUNT(*) as cnt_2
      FROM Test2
      GROUP BY ID_Test1
     ) t2
     ON t1.id = t2.ID_Test1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT ID_Test1, SUM(positive) as sum_pos, SUM(negative) as sum_neg
      FROM Test3
      GROUP BY ID_Test1
     ) t3
     ON t1.id = t3.ID_Test1
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/546c24/11) is the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: SIR , HOW TO CREATE SQL FIDDLE?

Comment: @MohitKumar . . . Hint:  www.sqlfiddle.com.  If you have problems with that, there is always rextester and db-fiddle and no doubt others.